# click on second class name with the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors, greasemonkey

How do I click on another class with the same name?

HTML:

```
<span class="pointer" onclick="window.open('index','_blank');">ux</span>
<span class="pointer" onclick="window.open('index','_blank');">ux</span>
<span class="pointer" onclick="window.open('index','_blank');">ux</span>
<span class="pointer" onclick="window.open('index','_blank');">ux</span>
<span class="pointer" onclick="window.open('index','_blank');">ux</span>
```

code:

```
document.querySelector('.pointer').click()
```

Comment: Please elaborate your problem...!

Answer (score 3):

You can use,

```
$(".pointer:eq(1)")[0].click();
```

This will trigger the dom element click for the 2nd pointer element.

Or,

Instead of writing the inline code for function call, you can use jquery event handler which will give you more control over the current clicked object.

```
$(".pointer").click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
  window.open('index', '_blank');
});
```

Comment: also how do i hide it if one is clicked ?

Comment: which element do you need to hide?

Comment: supposed this one is clicked `$(".pointer:eq(1)")[0].click();` 
so after click it will also hide that element